# Webgl bindBufer and vertexAttribPointer depends on buffer size or not?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Does bindBuffer operation depends on binded buffer size? For example I have an array of indices I want to draw, also I have a few vertex buffer(sources of my vertices) first is 100 vertices and second is 10000000 vertices buffers(allready created buffers) for example. The question is that changing(or binding) vertex buffers depends on their sizes or not? Ofcource rendering and creating buffers depends on buffer size but for refine I'm interesting only bindBuffer operation performance.
Thank for any advice.

Please do not point out a meaning sequence of binding, I only iteresting on performance:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, coordinatesBuffer0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(sha.coordinates._pName, coordinatesBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, coordinatesBuffer1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(sha.coordinates._pName, coordinatesBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, coordinatesBuffer3);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(sha.coordinates._pName, coordinatesBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

etc. etc. etc and somewhere about

```
this.gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
this.gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexBuffer.numItems, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Comment: you might be interested in [this explanation of attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webgl/4818/state/16960/attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindBuffer` is just setting an internal *pointer* to the address of the given buffer, it is not correlated to buffer size.

Comment: Wow! It's great answer I've expected. thanks. Realy.